# Show that $\dim U + \dim U^{0} = \dim V$ (finite dimensions)

Tags: linear-algebra

I know this question has been asked here before but I wanted to take a different approach to this problem. I wanted to avoid the use of basis for $V$ or $V^{*}$. I started off by noting that the original problem is equivalent to saying that $U^{0} \cong V/U$

Note that there is a subspace of $V^{*}$ called $W$ such that $V^{*} = U^{0} \oplus W$ now this means we can define a projection map $p: V^{*} \to V^{*}$ such that if $v = u + w$ for $v \in V^{*}$, $u \in U^{0}$ and $w \in W$ then $p(v) = u$. Now this means that $\text{Im}(p) = U^{0}$ and $\ker(p) = W$ using this we might note that $U^{0} \cong V^{*}/\ker(p)$(inducing an isomorphism $h: V^{*}/\ker(p) \to U^{0}$)

Now we shift focus and note that there is an isomorphism $\psi: V \to V^{*}$. Also we have a quotient map $\eta: V \to V/U$.

I now defined a new map $g: V/U \to V^{*}/\ker(p)$ by $g(v + U) = \psi(v) + \ker(p)$. This map is clearly surjective.

To show that this map is injective I check the following: $g(v + U) = 0 + \ker(p)$ but this is the same as saying that $\psi(v) \in \ker(p)$ now this is where I get stuck is it true that $v \in U$, I think that it is true because if $v \in U$ then since $\psi$ is an isomorphism it cannot send $v$ into an annihilating functional (I am unable to justify this, however).

If what I have said is true this means that $v = 0$ meaning $g$ is injective meaning it is an isomorphism making $V/U \cong V^{*}/\ker(p) \cong U^{0}$

Thank you.

Comment: Before even thinking about surjectivity or injectivity, how do you know that $g$ is well-defined?

Comment: Because I fixed the subspace $W$